# When I intent the arrayList's data, and how can I get those data in the second activity and setText and Image?

Tags: java, android

I have made a Song List using ArrayList, and I got all the information and it can be passed to the second activity and open it on a new page. 
What I want to have is when I click the song list, then it opens in a new page, and the new page shows the details and the image of the song.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView_Main=findViewById(R.id.listView_Main);

    final Song song1 = new Song("Love Story","Taylor Swift","September 12,2008", "$1.29");
    Song song2 = new Song("Lover","Taylor Swift","August 23,2019", "$1.29" );
    Song song3 = new Song("I Forgot That You Existed", "Taylor Swift", "August 23,2019", "$1.29");
    Song song4 = new Song("The Archer", "Taylor Swift", "August 23,2019", "$1.29");
    Song song5 = new Song("I Think He Knows","Taylor Swift", "August 23,2019", "$1.29");

    final List<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    songs.add(song1);
    songs.add(song2);
    songs.add(song3);
    songs.add(song4);
    songs.add(song5);

      MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(this, songs);
      listView_Main.setAdapter(adapter);

     listView_Main.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

             Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),SongDetailActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("currentSong",(Serializable) songs.get(i));
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
}
```

But my problem is in the second activity, I don't know how to get the detail of the song, and the images by using the setText.
So, I have made the song details in the String.xml file. 
How can I get those details and the image in the second activity?
Also, I don't know how to get the position of the song list in the second activity, I mean the position of which song that I click, and It show the detail of that song I had clicked.

//Here is the second activity of the Song Details.//////

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_song_detail);

    textViewSongDetail=findViewById(R.id.textView_SongDetail);
    imageViewSongDetail=findViewById(R.id.image_SongDetail);

    Song currentSong=(Song)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("currentSong");
}
```

Comment: If you want to use position in Second Activity then you have to pass position as well.
intent.putExtra("POSITION",i); 

Also in second activity 
get postion 
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("POSITION")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure you've implemented Serializable in your model class Song. Than your code will work fine.
And to receive the position you can send -

```
intent.putExtra("position", i);   // to send 

getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);  //to receive (-1 is default value)
```

Comment: When I get it, then how can I use it, is using the for loop to get it or other method. I mean when I click song 3, then It show the detail of song 3, I had use the for-loop to get the position, but doesn't work.

Comment: getIntent().getSerializableExtra will give you the song which was clicked in previous activity, no need of for loop in SongDetailActivity.

Comment: OK, I got it.  Thank you

Comment: @DaYeMai if it worked please mark the answer as correct. Thank you :)

Comment: one more thing, please.  How to setText or Image?  I mean how to use that "currentSong" of the position for song 1 or song 2 to setText?  Now I got textView.setText(R.string.song_detail);    But I didn't get the idea of how to setText for the "currentSong" of the positions.

Comment: textView.setText(currentSong.getSongName()) where getSongName() is a getter in your Song model class.
If you have more doubt post another question with code and all your doubts.